# Always use _ instead of - on Woocommerce product attribute's slug

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, slug, custom-taxonomy

Apparently Woocommerce seems to have the bad habit of changing the way over time it creates its slugs. Sometimes it puts all words together, sometimes uses _ and sometimes -, depending on the Woocommerce version.

This is creating me a huge problem since my shop is connected to an external warehouse software that connects both physical shop with woocommerce shop warehouse. Unfortunately, in order for the connection to work correctly, the attribute slugs must always use _ instead of -.

I wonder if there is some automatic way to do this? Perhaps some tweek I can do on the functions.php or some Woocommerce file I can edit? And if possible, how could I do that?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The product attribute **taxonomy** slugs begin all by `pa_` *(as **p**roduct **a**ttribute)*.

Since a long time, if there is a white space (+ some other characters) they are replaced by a dash `-` and prohibited characters are removed. It's no more complicated than that.

For the connection to your external warehouse use in beetween **`str_replace()`** for the slugs conversions, this way:

```
// Here $taxonomy is the woocommerce product attribute slug
$right_slug = str_replace( array( 'pa_', '-' ), array( '', '_' ), $taxonomy );
```

It will:

- Remove `pa_` from the begining (when it appear),
- Replace all `-` by `_`.

This should solve your problems.

Comment: I am very sorry if I am asking for too much, but I didn't really understand if that should be on functions.php of my child-theme or if I should place it on the wc-attribute-functions.php?

Comment: As you don't explain how is maid the connexion between Woocommerce and your client warehouse software or whatever, I can't go further with that. My code for the moment is just a simple code line that do the slug conversion. With more details about how things are connected I should be able to complete my answer.